# Trouble returning items from an array

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I'm just starting out with AHK and am teaching myself how to read a text file that consists of 4 columns, space and tab delimeters, and an unknown number of rows.

I'm trying to grab the first token of any lines that contain the string "xcal", store that first token (%A_Index% = 1, right?) in my array (RunNum), and then retrieve all the stored numbers, displaying them in a MsgBox.

```
#SingleInstance, Force

RunNum :=  Object() ; Initialize temporary array

; ----------------- Read LIST.TAB.   ---------------------------

IfNotExist, %A_ScriptDir%\LIST.TAB
{
    MsgBox,48,Error!, LIST.TAB was not found.
        ExitApp
}
else
{
    RunCount = 1 ; Set Run counter 
    Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\list.tab ; Read config file
    {
        IfInString, A_LoopReadLine,  xcal ; If current line contains the word 'xcal'...
        {
            Loop, Parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Space% %A_Tab% ; Parse through current line of config file, space and tab delimiter 
            {
                if  (%A_Index% = 1) ; Continue if at the first element/token of string
                {   
                 RunNum[RunCount] :=  A_LoopField ; Store current field in RunNum array
                 RunCount+=1  ; Increase counter           
                }
            }               
        }                                         
    }
 MsgBox % RunNum[RunCount]
}
```

Comment: the right is `if A_Index = 1` no percent signs

Comment: Also the innermost `if` seems to lack curly braces around the two lines that follow.

Comment: Removing the %'s doesnt change anything. And I mustve forgot to add the curly braces in the if loop, but they are there in my actual script.

I just dont understand how I can display the value in the array, or if the array is even populating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this data based on your description:

```
1234    xcal    RandomJunk
4567    Nocal   RandomJunk
8910    xcal    RandomJunk
```

Code:

```
#SingleInstance, Force

RunNum := [] ; No reason to use Object()

; ----------------- Read LIST.TAB.   ---------------------------
If !(FileExist(A_ScriptDir "\list.tab")) {
    MsgBox,48,Error!, LIST.TAB was not found.
        ExitApp
} else {
    Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\list.tab ; Read config file
    {
        If (InStr(A_LoopReadLine,  "xcal")) ; If current line contains the word 'xcal'...
            RunNum.push(StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, A_Space A_tab).1)             
    }

For Each, Value in RunNum
    YourNumbers .= Value "`n"
 MsgBox % YourNumbers
}
```

Results:

```
1234
8910
```

Comment: So that's how! And  that's way more streamline too, thanks Ahkcoder!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Please read through documentation (the tutorial is excellent) on the commands/functions that you don't understand, it's all in there! Also practice, practice, practice!

Comment: I cant find any reference to the ".1" in the "InStr" function index page. Does it just mean start at the first element of the array?

Comment: Ahkcoder, the reason Im asking about the ".1" is because your code returns the entire line of each xcal line, not just the first token. I cant figure how to just grab the first token.

Comment: @Rich M: StrSplit() creates a [Simple Array](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays), the .1 indicates we are asking for the first element in the array it created. StrSplit splits a string based on the given Delimiter (in your case you indicated it was a Space Tab). If the delimiter isn't correct, then your string won't be split as such (maybe it should be just Space?) I can't know unless you show me the actual file you are trying to parse, I based my code example on the data you gave. Share the actual file you are trying to parse, I'll write a solution you asked for.

Comment: OK it works when its just "A_tab". (It was a tab delimited file) But it doesnt work when both the space and tab delimeters are in the script for whatever reason. Thanks so much for all your help though!

Comment: I figured out if there is no space between them, both delimiters can be in the function! Im learning! Lol